# ArangoDB: Unable to initialize RocksDB engine: IO error

Tags: arangodb, rocksdb

I'm not able to run ArangoDB due to below error.

**FATAL [fe3df] {startup} unable to initialize RocksDB engine: IO error: No such file or directoryNewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: C:\Users\Waseeq\Downloads\ArangoDB3-3.8.1_win64\ArangoDB3-3.8.1_win64\var\lib\arangodb3\engine-rocksdb/000062.ldb: The system cannot find the file specified.\r\n; Maybe your filesystem doesn't provide required features? (Cifs? NFS?)**

**ArangoDB version: 3.8.1**

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Run the installer once you download Arango, don't just extract the file and run it out of there.

Comment: This is not a new database, i was using it from long time but from few days its not working. there is a sst file missing at var\lib\arangodb3\engine-rocksdb/